# How would I cURL download and run an exe file, on the same line (Powershell)?

Tags: powershell, curl

Currently what I am doing is this:

```
curl https://linktoexe/app.exe | -
```

Why is this not working, and how can I accomplish this in the same(ish) method as I put above? I know you can do this with Python scripts, then run them with `python -` which runs them from 'stdin', but I don't know how to do it with .exe files.

Thanks,
Henry Sargeant

Comment: The reason `python -` works with _stdin_ is because it is a text file, you generally cannot do this with executables.

Comment: What would be another way to do this then with Powershell?

Comment: Download to file, then execute.

Comment: Gotcha, thanks brother!

Answer (score 0):

A lovely person ([@zett42](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7571258/zett42), has provided me with the solution in the comments of my problem. Thanks brother!